# Refresh ListView After Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Is it possible to refresh ListView Control ? For example after the page postback I want ListView to iterate again his items. Is there a way to do this ? (ListView is binded with EntityDataSource)

Comment: A bit of code will be appriciated .

Answer (score 2):

If the source has changed then rebind it, otherwise don't.

This will be the same way as you're doing now, something like:

```
list.DataSource = source;
list.DataBind();
```

Generally the problem people have is that they *don't* want controls to rebind, and are pleased to discover the availability of `IsPostBack`, and *that* I can understand, but without this knowledge (or even with it and actively leaving logic out) this is what would happen by default for you, so, curious, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, use the `DataBind` method for that.